# Couchbase Failing on StoreJson

Tags: c#, asp.net, couchbase

I'm having an issue using Couchbase with the newest version of the .NET assemblies (1.2).  My goal is to select 150,000 records from my current Oracle Database and migrate the entire object into the Couchbase Data-Bucket.  The 150k records are stored as objects in objectList (belo

The following code seems to give me somewhere between 100,000 - 120,000 failures every time I run it.  Does anyone know what may be the cause or how to best debug this issue?  However, every time I run it, different sets of objects are added into the data-bucket, which makes me even more confused.

```
int failures = 0;
foreach (var obj in objectList) {

var result = client.StoreJson(StoreMode.Set, obj.Id, obj);
if (!result) failures++;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging purposes I would suggest that instead of using the extension method `StoreJson` you use `ExecuteStore`. You will have to perform the serialization step as well.

The difference between these methods is that while StoreJson returns just a `bool` value, ExecuteStore returns the actual `IOperationResult` which will tell you what happend. There is a status code on that object and the exception message, if any.

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-net-1.2/api-reference-set.html

Comment: FYI - There are ExecuteXXX methods coming to the JSON extensions.  http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/NCBC-179

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I expand the object, it shows "Failed to process response." - StatusCode 134, which corresponds to x86, which from this link says: Temporary Failure.  (http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped#Response_Status)

Comment: Could this mean the Ram or total Memory is insufficient to support the bulk inserting operations?

Comment: @GW - I haven't seen this one, but have a look at the first answer here - it seems that it is a out of memory issue which could be fixed by leaving couchbase some time to persist the data before processing another batch: http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/errors-add-operation

Comment: Thanks; I'll mark the original response as Answered, as it provides a great starting point to debugging the issue.

Comment: Increasing the  Ram/Quota size does seem to provide better reliability.

Currently, I have a (while !result.Success) { // Retry } running to ensure that records are inserted.  

There are 150k+ records, so it isn't a "small" insert, so this may very well be a potential cause.  

Thanks.

Comment: @GW I'm glad you found it helpful